# Shell Scripting: Print directory names and files with specifics

Tags: linux, shell, sh

In my script, I am asking the user to input a directory and then list all the files in that specific directory. What I want to do with that is to make the display a little better in which I would be able to display a "/" if the item in the directory is another directory and if it is an executable file (not an executable directory), print with a **".

This is what I have:

```
echo “Directory: “
read thing
for var123 in $thing*
do
        echo $var123
done
```

In a directory I have a few folders and a few scripts that have the execute permission. when I run the script I want to say

> /folder1/subfolder1/
>
> /folder1/subfolder2/
>
> /folder1/file1*
>
> /folder1/file2*

I am new to this and have no clue what I am doing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check and make sure the user inputs something that ends in a `/` first.

e.g.

```
[[ $thing =~ '/'$ ]] || thing="$thing/"
```

Also check if it exists

e.g.

```
[[ -d $thing ]] || exit 1
```

Then for checking if it's a directory use the `-d` test as above. To check if executable file use `-x`. So putting that all together, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo “Directory: “
read thing
[[ $thing =~ '/'$ ]] || thing="$thing/"
[[ -d $thing ]] || exit 1
for var123 in "$thing"*
do
  if [[ -f $var123 && -x $var123 ]]; then 
    echo "$var123**"
  elif [[ -d $var123 ]]; then 
    echo "$var123/"
  else
    echo "$var123"
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls -F` is your friend here - if you want to do it for the current directory:

```
ls -F
```

If you want to do it for all files & subfolders of the current directory:

```
find * -exec ls -Fd {} \;
```

... and for a given directory:

```
echo "Directory: "
read DIR

find $DIR/* -exec ls -Fd {} \;
```

Edit: `ls -F` will append a `/` to directories and a `*` to executables.  If you want `**` instead, just use sed to replace them:

```
find $DIR/* -exec ls -Fd {} \; | sed 's/\*$/&&/'
```

And this approach works in ***all*** shells, not just bash.

Comment: `ls -F` is definitely the way to go if all op wanted is some identifier of file type, but [tag:ls] has a recursive option so no need for [tag:find], e.g. `ls -RF`

Comment: But ls -RF gives you completely different output than ls -F ;)

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. :D but it didn't match what he wanted.

Comment: Oh, neither does this - didn't notice he wanted TWO asterisks for executables.. ls -F does only 1.  sed can fix that.